# Select a fixed number of records from a particular user in a sql result

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables - users and articles.

users:

- user_id (int)
- name (varchar)

articles:

- article_id (int)
- user_id (int)
- title (varchar)
- description (text)

In my application I need to display 20 RANDOM articles on a page.

My query is like this:

```
SELECT a.title
     , a.description
     , u.name 
  FROM articles a
  JOIN users u 
 USING (user_id)
 ORDER 
    BY RAND()
 LIMIT 20
```

A user can have any number of articles in the database.

Now the problem is sometimes out of 20 results, there are like 9-10 articles from one single user.

I want those 20 records on the page to not contain more than 3 (or say 4) articles from a particular user.

Can I achieve this through SQL query. I am using PHP and MySQL.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: *"Can I achieve this through SQL query"* I don't think so. Maybe in a stored procedure. But what I would suggest is to keep all(or most of) articles in a cache, and apply that logic on it.

Comment: Using stored procedures would require some learning. So I need to find any other solution. I wonder why MySQL has no option for this particular problem.

Comment: You answerd your own question, that is because it is very *"particular"*. *"not contain more than 3 (or say 4) articles from a particular user"* this is programming's role, not database's.

Comment: Not sure how I can do this in the best possible way via Programming. May be fetching 30 records and then displaying 20 records as per my requirement?

Comment: Well, you have a nice answer by @Ctznkane525. If that works for you, then ok. But I would still prefer caching a set of articles and apply the logic over it. Some loops and ifs and you're done. That is what this site does, caching, and it is indeed very fast.

Comment: i dont know who is gentle man given down vote for this question.

Comment: It's a tricky question and there are two answers below . Some of this is down to your own database size now and what it might get to. I'd give the SQL one a chance see what you get regards performance, otherwise I think you might be looking at something like I've hammered together. 

Good q BTW.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your help. I will try both the inception queries (by Ctznkane525) and Richard's solution to see what fits well. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could try this?

```
SELECT * FROM
(

    SELECT B.* FROM 
    (
        SELECT A.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.USER_ID ORDER BY A.R) USER_ROW_NUMBER
        FROM
        (
             SELECT a.title, a.description, u.name, RND() r FROM articles a
             INNER JOIN users u USING (user_id)
        ) A

    ) B
    WHERE B.USER_ROW_NUMBER<=4
) C
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20
```

Comment: had to make a couple minor changes...might have a couple syntax issues...but the principal concept i believe is there

Comment: perhaps better than my answer. The trouble with some of this RAND stuff and functions like ROW_NUMBER is that over time don't they just get slow?

Comment: @RichardHousham no mentioning 3 subselects. But is a nice answer btw.

Comment: Yeah, with things like RAND it's often a good idea to limit the amount down based off something like date just so you aren't looking at the whole table.

Comment: Wow. This looks like inception - query within a query within a query. I think I understand the concept. Also limiting the records down using date is a nice suggestion. Thanks guys for your help.

Comment: I doubt the OP's MySQL version is up to cte requirements

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, intresting I don't think this is possible through a pure sql query. 
My best idea would be to have an array of the articles that you'll eventually display query the database and use the standard `SELECT * FROM Articles ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20`

The go through them, making sure that you have indeed got 20 articles and no one has breached the rules of 3/4 per user.

Have another array of users to exclude, perhaps using their user id as an index and value of a count.

As you go through add them to your final array, if you find any user that hits you rule add them to the array.

Keep running the random query, excluding users and articles until you hit your desired amount.

Let me try some code (it's been a while since I did php)

```
   $finalArray = [];
    $userArray = [];

while(count($finalArray) < 20) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM Articles ";

if(count($finalArray) > 0) {
   $query = $query . " WHERE articleID NOT IN(".$finalArray.")";
   $query = $query . " AND userID NOT IN (".$userArray.filter(>4).")";
} 

$query = $query . " ORDER BY Rand()";



$result = mysql_query($query);
foreach($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    if(in_array($finalArray,$row) == false) {
           $finalArray[] = $row;
     }
     if(in_array($userArray,$row[userId]) == false) {
          $userArray[$row[userId]] = 1;
     }
     else {
         $userArray[$row[userId]]  = $userArray[$row[userId]] + 1;
}

}
```

Comment: I've hammered some code together to flesh out how I would do this. Some bits like turning the array into a comma array and user.filter(>4) you'll have to work out for yourself - but at a guess you'll probably only run that query once or twice depending on your user base.,

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your help. I will try both the inception queries (by Ctznkane525) and your logic to see what fits well. Thanks again.